# understanding a modular javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, modular

I'm trying to write 'better' javascript.

Below is one pattern I've found, and am trying to adopt. However, I'm slightly confused about its use.

Say, for example, I've got a page called "Jobs". Any JS functionality on that page would be encapsulated in something like:

```
window.jobs = (function(jobs, $, undefined){
    return {
        addNew: function(){
            // job-adding code
        }
    }
})(window.jobs|| {}, jQuery);

$(function(){
    $('.add_job').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.jobs.addNew();
    });
});
```

As you can probably deduct, all I've done is replaced all the code that would have sat inside the anonymous event-handler function, with a call to a function in my global jobs object. I'm not sure why that's a good thing, other than it's reduced the possibility of variable collisions and made the whole thing a bit neater, but that's good enough for me.

The - probably fairly obvious - question is: all my event-binding init-type stuff is still sitting outside my shiny new jobs object: where should it be? Inside the jobs object? Inside the return object inside the jobs object? Inside an init() function?

I'm just trying to get a sense of a stable, basic framework for putting simple functionality in. I'm not building JS apps, I'd just like to write code that's a little more robust and maintainable than it is currently. Any and all suggestions are warmly welcomed :)

Comment: Many thanks for the extremely helpful answers; I know there's a wealth of information on there, from the Crockfords and Osmanis and Resigs, but it's very helpful to have these concepts explained in relation to your own code. I'm going to mark jAndy's response as accepted, as although I'm clearly in no position to state which is the "correct" solution, his answer seemed to explain best how the approach I'm taking should be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break down your application in whatever number of `modules` / `objects` you like too.

For instance, you can have another object / module which caches and defines all your DOM nodes and another one, which just handles any event. So for instance:

```
(function ( win, doc, $, undef ) {
    win.myApp = win.myApp || { };

    var eventHandler = {
        onJobClick: function( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            myApp.addNew();
        }
    };

    var nodes = (function() {
        var rootNode = $( '.myRootNode' ),
            addJob = rootNode.find( '.add_job' );

        return {
            rootNode: rootNode,
            addJob: addJob
        };
    }());

    $(function() {
        myApp.nodes.addJob.on( 'click', myApp.handler.onJobClick );
    });

    myApp.nodes = nodes;
    myApp.handler = eventHandler;
}( this, this.document, jQuery ));
```

It doesn't really matter *how* you create singletons in this (module) pattern, either as literal, constructor, `Object.create()` or whatnot. It needs to fit your requirements.

But you should try to create as many specific modules/objects as necesarry. Of course, if makes even more sense to separate those singletons / modules / objects into multiple javascript files and load them on demand and before you can say knife, you're in the world of modular programming patterns, dealing with `requireJS` and AMD or CommonJS modules.

Comment: The idea is to keep module (JavaScript files) scopes isolated. But we still need communication between the modules. That can be easily achieved going CommonJS way - export whatever you want from a module by `exports` and import in a module by `require`. You can compile CommonJs modules to a single file suitable for a browser with 
https://github.com/dsheiko/cjsc or http://browserify.org. It is implemented even in a more explicit way in ES6 - http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules

There is another way. You can define a Mediator object that is injected into every module scope

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation-wise, you're fine: you could even just declare `addNew` in the jQuery closure and you'd still avoid the global scope. I think what you're getting at is more of implementing something close to an MVC architecture.

Something I like to do is create an object that you instantiate with a DOM element and that takes care of its own bindings/provides methods to access its controls etc.

Example:

```
   // (pretend we're inside a closure already)
   var myObj = function(args){
       this.el = args.el; // just a selector, e.g. #myId
       this.html = args.html;
       this.bindings = args.bindings || {};
   }

   myObj.prototype.appendTo = function(elem){
       elem.innerHTML += this.html;
       this.bindControls();
   };

   myObj.prototype.remove = function(){
       $(this.el).remove(); // using jQuery
   };

   myObj.prototype.bindControls = function(){
       for(var i in this.bindings){ // event#selector : function
           var boundFunc = function(e){ return this.bindings[i].call(this,e); };
           $(this.el).on(i,boundFunc);
       }
   };
```

Comment: This sounds to me quite like a jQuery plugin pattern, would that be accurate? In any case, it's very useful to see it broken down like that. Thank you - here, have an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it right now is exactly how I do it also, I typically create the window objects inside the anonymous function itself and then declare inside that (in this case: jClass = window.jClass).

```
(function (jClass, $, undefined) { 

    /// <param name="$" type="jQuery" />

    var VERSION      = '1.31';
    UPDATED_DATE = '7/20/2012';

    // Private Namespace Variables
    var _self         = jClass; // internal self-reference
    jClass        = window.jClass; // (fix for intellisense)
    $             = jQuery; // save rights to jQuery (also fixes vsdoc Intellisense)

    // I init my namespace from inside itself
    $(function () {
        jClass.init('branchName');
    });

    jClass.init = function(branch) {
      this._branch = branch;
      this._globalFunctionality({ globalDatePicker: true });
      this._jQueryValidateAdditions();

      //put GLOBAL IMAGES to preload in the array
      this._preloadImages( [''] );

      this._log('*******************************************************');
      this._log('jClass Loaded Successfully :: v' + VERSION + ' :: Last Updated: ' + UPDATED_DATE);
      this._log('*******************************************************\n');
};

    jClass._log = function() {
    //NOTE: Global Log (cross browser Console.log - for Testing purposes)
    //ENDNOTE 

    try { console.log.apply(console, arguments); }  
    catch (e) {
        try { opera.postError.apply(opera, arguments); }
        catch (e) { /* IE Currently shut OFF : alert(Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ' '));*/ }
    }   
};

}(window.jClass= window.jClass|| {}, jQuery));
```

The reason I leave them completely anonymous like this, is that let's say in another file I want to add much more functionality to this jClass. I simply create another:

```
(function jClass, $, undefined) {

jClass.newFunction = function (params) {
    // new stuff here
};

}(window.jClass = window.jClass || {}, jQuery))
```

As you can see I prefer the object.object notation, but you can use object literals object : object, it's up to you!

Either way by leaving all of this separate, and encapsulated without actual page logic makes it easier to have this within a globalJS file and every page on your site able to use it. Such as the example below.

```
jClass._log('log this text for me');
```

You don't want to intertwine model logic with your business logic, so your on the right path separating the two, and allowing for your global namespace/class/etc to be more flexible!

Answer (score 0):

You can find here a comprehensive study on module pattern here: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html It covers all the aspects of block-scoped module approach. However in practice you gonna have quite a number files encapsulating you code, so the question is how to combine them property. AMD... multiple HTTP requests produced by every module loading will rather harm your page response time. So you can go with CommonJS compiled to a single JavaScript file suitable for in-browser use. Take a look how easy it is http://dsheiko.github.io/cjsc/